# flutter:get the last document from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have many document inside a collection of firebase. But i want to retrieve only the last document which is present at the bottom. You can see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRvYI.png) . i want to retrieve the highlighted document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **last** in following way to get last document.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("data").snapshots().last
```

This will give you only last element.

Comment: I want last 7 uploaded documents how can I perform that